# install opencv on heroku: compiled slug size is too large

Tags: python, node.js, opencv, heroku

I want to install opencv for my face-detection node.js app on heroku by using this buildpack: https://github.com/slobdell/heroku-buildpack-python-opencv

So I just did:

```
heroku buildpack:set https://github.com/slobdell/heroku-buildpack-python-opencv
```

But then I'll receive this error:

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
remote: -----> Python + OpenCV + Numpy + Scipy app detected
remote: -----> Generating environment
remote:        Fetching...
remote:        Unpacking...
remote: -----> Creating environment variables.
remote: -----> Buildpack installed.
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> monitor, receive
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing... 


remote:  !   Compiled slug size: 548.5MB is too large (max is 300MB).


remote:  !   See: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-size
remote:  !     Push failed: slug archive could not be created
remote:  !     Please try pushing again.
remote:  !     If the problem persists, see http://help.heroku.com/ and provide Request ID 3123dc0c-3f9f-4da1-9223-16531769b6ae.
remote: 
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to arcane-hollows-8678.
remote:
```

I've got absolutely no idea what I'm doing wrong. As far as I know, I'll make my heroku app to upload opencv and my app and then compress it. But how can I have an influence on the size of opencv?

Comment: Why is this tagged as `node.js` ?